# Como realizar um auto-update em um sistema web local?

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache, migrations, bitbucket

Fala galera, blz?

Desenvolvi um sistema web (em CodeIgniter) para um cliente e o mesmo roda numa máquina local dentro do seu escritório. Sempre que preciso atualizar o sistema, eu realizo os seguintes passos:

1. Acesso a máquina servidor via TeamViewer;
2. Abro o [CMDER](http://cmder.net);
3. Acesso a minha conta no Bitbucket para dar um `git pull`;
4. Executo as migrações necessárias;

Pensando nesses sistemas *desktops* que buscam uma nova versão de forma automática e se atualizão, é possível fazer uma rotina nesse sistema web para realizar a mesma coisa? Buscar no Bitbucket (ou outro servidor web) uma nova versão e em seguida fazer o update?

Agradeço as sugestões.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma bem simples é:

Armazenando o seu login do repositório no servidor:

```
cd c:\seu_repositorio\
git config credential.helper cache
```

Esse comando fará cache das suas credenciais na próxima vez que fizer um pull/push.

Uma vez feito o cache, não será mais solicitado usuário e senha

Dessa forma você poderá criar uma tarefa agendada no windows, que executa um arquivo php automaticamente, que pode conter um código para executar um simples `git pull` ou você também pode fazer outras validações no código, por exemplo:

- Checar o código md5 de algum arquivo, se mudou desde a última versão, aí você atualiza faz o pull do repositório git, senão não faz nada.
- Nesse código PHP, você também pode executar outras ações como alguma atualização de banco de dados, exclusão de arquivos antigos, limpeza de logs, etc...
- Da mesma forma que você pode fazer o controle pelo repositório GIT, você poderia disponibilizar um pacote zipado em uma hospedagem e ficar baixando os arquivos dessa hospedagem, fazendo o controle dentro do arquivo php também.